# SQL expressions that should be equivalent, but aren't?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a problem where we need to join data across multiple tables as filters for a set of users.  The subqueries are giving me the same result when using only one condition as the "simple" query with only one conditon, but when I use multiple subqueries, I'm getting something way higher, like it's not filtering down and performing the AND operation like I would have expected.   I've verified on a simple recreation that the results of the two subqueries and their "simple" equivalent are identical - so it's some syntactical error on my part in how I'm checking user_id's in the two subqueries.

What is the syntactical sugar that I'm missing to use the two subqueries together like a normal AND filter so that the second example gives me 32 like I would expect?  If it's specific to software, I'm doing this query on an AWS Snowflake database.

The "correct" query can be done on a single table like so:

Ex. 1: This gives me 32:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table_a.user_id)
FROM   table_a 
WHERE  cond_1 AND cond_2
```

Ex. 2: This gives me 104:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT table_b.user_id ) 
FROM   table_b 
WHERE ( 
    table_b.user_id IN (SELECT table_a.user_id FROM table_a WHERE cond_1)
    AND 
    table_b.user_id IN (SELECT table_a.user_id FROM table_a WHERE cond_2)
)
```

**NOTE**
For context, I verified that the subqueries are functioning and giving the same data as the simple WHERE conditions:

gives me a result of 25:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table_a.user_id)
FROM   table_a 
WHERE  cond_1
```

gives me a result of 25:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT table_b.user_id )
FROM   table_b 
WHERE ( 
    table_b.user_id IN (SELECT table_a.user_id FROM table_a WHERE cond_1)
)
```

gives me a result of 48:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table_a.user_id)
FROM   table_a 
WHERE  cond_2
```

gives me a result of 48:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT table_b.user_id )
FROM   table_b 
WHERE ( 
    table_b.user_id IN (SELECT table_a.user_id FROM table_a WHERE cond_2)
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no relationship between:

```
WHERE  cond_1 AND cond_2
```

and:

```
WHERE (table_b.user_id IN (SELECT table_a.user_id FROM table_a WHERE cond_1) AND 
      table_b.user_id IN (SELECT table_a.user_id FROM table_a WHERE cond_2)
```

The first version is requiring that the conditions be met in the SAME row in `table_a`.  The second is requiring that the `user_id` meets the conditions, but they can be in different rows in `a`.

Answer (score 0):

This dosen't also make sense

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table_a.user_id)
FROM   table_a 
WHERE  cond_1 AND cond_2
```

gives you 32

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table_a.user_id)
FROM   table_a 
WHERE  cond_1
```

and less contrained set from the same table gives 25